# Type erasure with method using `Self` as parameter

Tags: swift, range, protocols, type-erasure

I'm trying to make a type erasure around `Range` and `ClosedRange` but I'm being stuck because they have some methods which take `Self` as parameter.

All types erasure samples found on the internet don't deal with that case.

Am I trying to do something impossible ?

Here's my implementation (simplified) :

```
protocol RangeType {
    associatedtype _Bound: Comparable

    func overlaps(_ other: Self) -> Bool
}

struct AnyRange<Bound: Comparable>: RangeType {
    typealias _Bound = Bound

    private let _overlaps: (AnyRange<Bound>) -> Bool

    init<R: RangeType>(_ range: R) where R._Bound == Bound {
        // Cannot assign value of type (R) -> Bool to type (AnyRange<...>) -> Bool
        self._overlaps = range.overlaps
    }

    func overlaps(_ other: AnyRange<Bound>) -> Bool {
        return _overlaps(other)
    }
}

extension Range: RangeType {
    typealias _Bound = Bound
}

extension ClosedRange: RangeType {
    typealias _Bound = Bound
}
```

Comment: Still no answers on this? the more I think, maybe it's wrong. I have something like this in my code too and it gave me headaches trying to come up with solutions... MAYBE it's something we think is possible because we've been coding OOD our whole life, and these two things just don't mix&match 

Comment: I also read somewhere, if you use `Self` in result of a function or variable in protocol, it's not generic anymore :/

Comment: The only answer i found, used classes. http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/type-erasers-in-swift/

Comment: @farzadshbfn The problem here is a bit different because comparison of different types is not defined with `Self` type requirements. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Before I propose my solution to the problem, first note that what you are trying to do may not be defined. The protocol `RangeType` ensures that `overlaps(_:)` is defined for instances whose type is the same as the type that is implementing the function. The type erasure you are attempting to get by mimicking that of `AnyIterator` cannot be achieved this way because while `AnyRange` may guarantee that the bounds are identical, the actual underlying types themselves may not be (a requirement of the protocol).

However, that is solved here. If you wish, you may add a special case to handle comparisons between two different types (although evaluation to `false` as is done here is perhaps desirable)

```
protocol RangeType {
    associatedtype _Bound: Comparable
    func overlaps(_ other: Self) -> Bool
}

struct RangeComparison<Range, Element>: Equatable where Range: RangeType, Range._Bound == Element {
    static func ==(lhs: RangeComparison<Range, Element>, rhs: RangeComparison<Range, Element>) -> Bool { lhs.range.overlaps(rhs.range) }
    var range: Range
}

struct AnyRange<Bound: Comparable>: RangeType {
    
    // MARK: RangeType
    
    typealias _Bound = Bound
    
    // Calls the closure of the `_overlaps` property which shields each type and allows self to be passed through
    func overlaps(_ other: AnyRange<Bound>) -> Bool { _overlaps.closure(other, self) }
    
    // Shielding structure. Allows us to compare to `AnyRange` instances
    private struct OverlapContainer<A, B> {
        private(set) var closure: (A, B) -> Bool
        init(closure: @escaping (A, B) -> Bool) { self.closure = closure }
    }
    private var _overlaps: OverlapContainer<AnyRange<Bound>, Self>
    
    // Holds reference to the actual range type. Note that if this is a class type, a strong reference will be created
    private let range: Any
    
    /**
        Represents this particular type. Should not be called elsewhere in the structure as the cast would fail if `RT != R`
        passed to the initiliazer
     
        NOTE: `RT` as the generic type is used instead of `R` to keep us aware of this fact
    */
    private nonmutating func rangeComparison<RT: RangeType>() -> RangeComparison<RT, Bound> { RangeComparison<RT, Bound>(range: range as! RT) }
    
    init<R: RangeType>(_ range: R) where R._Bound == Bound {
        self.range = range
        self._overlaps = .init { other, this in
            
            let thisComparison: RangeComparison<R, Bound> = this.rangeComparison()
   
            // If the two types are the same, the comparison can be made
            if type(of: other.range).self == R.self {
                let otherComparison: RangeComparison<R, Bound> = other.rangeComparison()
                return thisComparison == otherComparison
            }
            else { print("Not the same type"); return false } // Otherwise the comparison is invalid
        }
    }
}

extension Range: RangeType {
    typealias _Bound = Bound
}

extension ClosedRange: RangeType {
    typealias _Bound = Bound
}

// Examples

let range: Range<Int> = .init(5...8)
let rangeII: ClosedRange<Int> = 1...6

let any: AnyRange<Int> = .init(range)
let anyII: AnyRange<Int> = .init(rangeII)

print(any.overlaps(anyII)) // false.` Range` is not the same type as `ClosedRange`


let rangeIII: ClosedRange<Double> = 3.0...5.5
let rangeIV: ClosedRange<Double> = 1.0...4.0

let anyIII: AnyRange<Double> = .init(rangeIII)
let anyIV: AnyRange<Double> = .init(rangeIV)

print(anyIII.overlaps(anyIV)) // true. Both are 'ClosedRange<Double>' and actually overlap one another
```

There is a lot here, so let me explain each piece

---

```
struct RangeComparison<Range, Element>: Equatable where Range: RangeType, Range._Bound == Element {
    static func ==(lhs: RangeComparison<Range, Element>, rhs: RangeComparison<Range, Element>) -> Bool { lhs.range.overlaps(rhs.range) }
    var range: Range
}
```

This structure is what is used to represent a given `AnyRange` type. As I mentioned, comparing any two `RangeType` instances is not defined if they are not of the same type. This provides a medium to ensure that this is the case as well as making it convenient to equate two `AnyRange` types through this structure.

The `rangeComparison<RT: RangeType>()` method uses the type of the `RangeType` (R) passed into the initializer and casts the `range` property (set as `Any` and assigned to the instance passed to the initializer) to this type to create a `RangeComparison` instance. The `range` property is what keeps hold of the actual underlying type.

---

```
private struct OverlapContainer<A, B> {
    private(set) var closure: (A, B) -> Bool
    init(closure: @escaping (A, B) -> Bool) { self.closure = closure }
}
private var _overlaps: OverlapContainer<AnyRange<Bound>, Self>
```

This structure actually allows us to (indirectly) make comparisons between two `AnyRange` instances through the `overlaps(_:)` method of `AnyRange` and a closure. We simply call the `_overlaps` property's `closure` property, supplying the other `AnyRange` instance and a **copy** of this instance. A copy is used to ensure that the closure can use `self` without having to use `self` , as the compiler will complain that "Escaping closure captures mutating `self` parameter" (hence the reason that `OverlapContainer` has two generic types).

```
init<R: RangeType>(_ range: R) where R._Bound == Bound {
    self.range = range
    self._overlaps = .init { other, this in
        
        let thisComparison: RangeComparison<R, Bound> = this.rangeComparison()

        // If the two types are the same, the comparison can be made
        if type(of: other.range).self == R.self {
            let otherComparison: RangeComparison<R, Bound> = other.rangeComparison()
            return thisComparison == otherComparison
        }
        else { print("Not the same type"); return false } // Otherwise the comparison is invalid
    }
}
```

Finally, we check if the two comparisons have the same type. If you try to specify each return type as `RangeComparison<R, Bound>`, it will compile but will crash if the types of each comparison's `range` property are not the same as the type `R` inferred from the generic initializer. You also "Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function", and so must specify a type for the result of `rangeComparison()`. For these two reasons, we check the type and then check if they overlap.